# Highlight the updated values when file data or version gets updated in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have created a dataflow in Azure Data Factory to find the differences between the two files, both the files have the same columns and structure. I would like to find/highlight the changes to each value rather than get the updated rows as the output which I am currently getting.

Example:

Current output -

| No. | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | jack@email.com |

Desired output -

| No. | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Jack |  |

I wish to either get the unchanged data in the row as NA or a blank or the changed data as highlighted in some way.

Dataflow -

[image]

Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be use the CRC function ( something like `crc32(columns())` and get the hash of each row for both the files and the  join on the hash1=hash2  and it should give you all the rows which has not been updated and have an exact match .

For the row with some changes , you can use also you can use join hash1!=hash2 clause bnut you will need one unique identfier .

Comment: I added the hashing to the columns and I am getting the updated/new rows. But I'm still not able to get just the individual updated values or just the values that have been updated in a row